# Update MariaDB table using a select query

Tags: sql-update, mariadb

So I have read a few posts on here but I cant seem to get this working on MySQL.

Pretty much I have a «count» of records with an `itemid` that I want to update into my `items` table based on the `itemid` into `items`.

This is what I have tried:

```
Update items
SET items.popularity = countitems.countofscriptiD
FROM items
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Count(scripts.ScriptID) AS CountOfScriptID, scripts.ItemID
FROM scripts GROUP BY scripts.ItemID) as countitems
ON
items.itemid =  countitems.itemid
```

Which returns a MySQL error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'FROM items INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(scripts.ScriptID) AS
> CountOfScriptID, scri' at line 3

If I change this to a SELECT query it works fine, either selecting from [items] or the count query however the update statement is failing!

Any advice would be great, from what I have read I can't see where I'm going wrong with this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The right way to do that, doing the join of tables before SET:

```
UPDATE items
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Count(scripts.ScriptID) AS CountOfScriptID, scripts.ItemID
FROM scripts GROUP BY scripts.ItemID) as countitems
ON
items.itemid =  countitems.itemid
SET items.popularity = countitems.countofscriptiD
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html