# Table is specified twice, both as target for 'UPDATE'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Table 'comp_analysis' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source of data.

```
UPDATE comp_analysis 
SET 
    big5_cat = (SELECT 
            b.category
        FROM
            big5 b
                JOIN
            comp_analysis c ON c.comp_keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', b.keyphrase, '%')
        WHERE
            b.script_order = (SELECT 
                    MIN(b2.script_order)
                FROM
                    big5 b2
                WHERE
                    (c.comp_keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', b2.keyphrase, '%')
                        AND b2.skip IS NULL
                        AND c.ca_id = @ca_id))
                AND c.ca_id = @ca_id);
```

I know it has something to do with the nested sub-queries and derived tables.  I've searched this site for answers, but I just can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

MariaDB 10.1.37 (MySQL 5.7)

-- Noob

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: Try this syntax, assuming it’s not a temp table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977955/update-table-using-a-select-query