# How do you update a table with data calculated from another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, multiple-tables

I'm trying to update a table of user accounts with their join date, the tables are a one to many/none collection. The `members_guild` table will have 1 or more entries for every guild the members has joined and I want to update the `members` table with the oldest date. I made a dbfiddle to help explain.

as you can see there is 3 users, `user3` is not in any of the guilds anymore but I want to keep them in the DB for logging purposes, their created date can be set to 1970 for now (ill manually fix them later) and `user1` is in 2 guilds and should have their `members.created` set to `2018-05-08 05:22:38`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=1d78120e695544cbd9dcece976c82f16

I have tried the UPDATE in the fiddle but it does not work, I'm assuming I would need to do a subquery or  a group by but have never done them inside an update statement

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `members.created` with min() if exists, otherwise leave it as it is.

```
UPDATE `members` m
SET m.created = coalesce(
      (SELECT MIN(mg.date_joined) 
      FROM `members_guild` mg
      WHERE m.account = mg.account), m.created) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
update members t1
inner join (select account, min(date_joined) date_joined from members_guild group by account) t2 
on t1.account = t2.account 
set t1.created = t2.date_joined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977955/update-table-using-a-select-query